# How do I make Mypy realize isinstance has already been called?

Tags: python, mypy

Is there any way to make Mypy realize I know what type of object I'm dealing with without calling `isinstance` in every if statement?  I would like to have helper functions to do that type of thing, but even when I have `isinstance` in the helper function, Mypy complains.  I've tried using `typing.Union` to get around this problem as well, but had similar issues.

```
import typing


class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def is_b(self):
        return isinstance(self, B)

    def is_c(self):
        return isinstance(self, C)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.b = b

        super().__init__(a)


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        self.c = c

        super().__init__(a)


a_list: typing.List[A] = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    b_or_c: A
    if i % 2 == 0:
        b_or_c = B('a' + str(i), 'b' + str(i))
    else:
        b_or_c = C('a' + str(i), 'c' + str(i))

    a_list.append(b_or_c)

for b_or_c in a_list:
    print(type(b_or_c))
    if b_or_c.is_b():
        print(b_or_c.b)  # Mypy Error: "A" has no attribute "b"

    if b_or_c.is_c():
        print(b_or_c.c)  # Mypy Error: "A" has no attribute "c"

    if isinstance(b_or_c, B):
        print(b_or_c.b)  # No Mypy Error

    if isinstance(b_or_c, C):
        print(b_or_c.c)  # No Mypy Error
```

Comment: `mypy` understands `isinstance` and `issubclass` because these are builtin functions, but not your custom checkers. You can always do an explicit cast, though: `if b_or_c.is_b(): print(cast(B, b_or_c).b)` etc.

Comment: Everything I read before posting this question indicated a cast function does not exist in Python. Can you link to the docs?

Comment: It's [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)

Answer (score 3):

Consider changing your API from this:

```
def is_c(self) -> bool:
    return isinstance(self, C)
```

to this:

```
def as_c(self) -> Optional[C]:
    if isinstance(self, C):
        return self
    return None
```

This would avoid the problem entirely. You can use it like this then:

```
c_opt = b_or_c.as_c()
if c_opt is not None:
    print(c_opt.c)
```

Comment: I don't have an `is_a` function.  `A` is an instance of `A`, and `B` and `C` extend `A`, so all objects in `a_list` will identify as instances of `A` all the time.  What I'm trying to do is differentiate between instances of type `B` and `C`. I have successfully done that actually, I just need Mypy to realize that :)

Comment: Sorry, I mean `is_b` and `is_c`. I will update the answer and add a usage example.

Comment: I figured that was a typo, but regardless, the result hasn't changed. Mypy still give an error. See image here https://pasteboard.co/Io8WWRI.png

Comment: @ubiquibacon you need to assign the return value of `as_c` to a new variable and only use the variable for this to work (like in the usage example I posted). Then mypy can infer that `c_opt` can go from `Optional[C]` to `C` within your `if` block.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well this is one way around the issue. Wish there was a cleaner way though.